# Django - Which model for a limited related data

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need a model that will be linked to a maximum of 3 data (of the same type).

Here is an example:
I have candidates that need to pass 3 steps to be recruited

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  step1 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True,)
  step2 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True,)
  step3 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True,)
```

For each step there is a review by several persons

```
class Review(models.Model):
  candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate)
  reviewer = models.ForeignKey(User)
  step1 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True,)
  step2 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True,)
  step3 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True,)
```

- Should I factorize these objects which would give me 4 objects instead of 2
  *such as `Candidate`, `Review`, `CandidateStep` and `ReviewStep`* ?

  - If yes, how can I limit to 3 steps ?
  - If not, how can easily iterate through the steps ?

---

**Example data**:

```
obj, created = Candidate.objects.get_or_create(
  user = SelectedCandidate
, defaults = {'step1': '', 'step2': '', 'step3': ''}
)
obj.step1 = 'I\'m really motivated'
obj.step2 = 'I\'m able to do this job'
obj.save()

obj, created = Review.objects.get_or_create(
  user = request.user
, defaults = {'step1': '', 'step2': '', 'step3': ''}
)
obj.step1 = 'He seems over motivated'
obj.save()
```

Comment: That sort of depends on what you are actually going to *put* in those fields.  Can you give some example data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about three objects:

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Step(model.Model):
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Review(models.Model):
    reviewer = models.ForeignKey(User)
    step =  models.OneToOneField(Step)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

> how can I limit to 3 steps ?

On view level. If you are going to use `ModelFromset`, using [max_num](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#limiting-the-number-of-editable-objects) option.

Comment: That's much better. However, I'm not going to use `ModelFormset` everywhere. Do you know how can I limit that in the object ? Maybe with a `Manager` or something.

Comment: @Glide You can check number of steps in `save` method, it's straightforward, but makes one extra DB hit. Or you can add `steps_num` field in `Candidate` model and update it with signals. It will be efficient, but a little denormalized. :-) I'd prefer the latter one.